# Kivy: Programa simple no me funciona

Tags: android, python, programación-móvil, kivy

estoy tratando de pasar un programa completo a Kivy, pero no me lo carga. Entonces he probado a hacer el programa más sencillo posible:

```
from kivy.app import App

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        print("HelloWorld")

TestApp().run()
```

Pero no me funciona, en cambio si funciona este otro código:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text='Hello World')

TestApp().run()
```

El problema que le veo a este otro código es que me crea un botón, y yo quiero mostrar textos de una forma en la que no sea mediante botones.

¿Por qué no me funciona el primer código?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función `print` se usa para mostrar informacion por la salida estándar (stdout), es decir la terminal/consola. Kivy crea una interfaz gráfica, al igual que si usas Tkinter necesitas un widget  apropiado para mostrar el texto (label, textview, textedit, etc).

Los dos principales widgets para mostrar/introducir texto en Kivy son las etiquetas (Label) y los Text input, puedes mirarte la documentación para más información:

[Kivy-Label](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.label.html)

[Kivy-Text input](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.textinput.html)

Un ejemplo que implementa labels y text inputs en Kivy seria:

**main.py:**

```
# config
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('kivy', 'keyboard_mode', 'system')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock
from itertools import cycle

import random

Builder.load_file('design.kv')

class MyWidget(BoxLayout):
    random_number = StringProperty()
    string = StringProperty()

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__()
        self.random_number = str(random.randint(1, 100))+'\n'
        self.listText = cycle(('Hola', 'soy', 'una', 'etiqueta'))
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.change_label_text, 0.6)

    def numero_aleatorio(self):
        self.random_number += str(random.randint(1, 100))+'\n'

    def change_label_text(self, *args):
        self.string = next(self.listText)

class myApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()
    def on_pause(self):
        return True
    def on_resume(self):
        pass

if __name__ in ('__main__', '__android__'):
    myApp().run()
```

**design.kv:**

```
<MyWidget>:
    BoxLayout:
        size: root.size

        Button:
            id: button1
            text: "Nuevo número"
            on_release: root.numero_aleatorio()

        TextInput:
            id: textInp2
            text: root.random_number
            multiline: True
            readonly: True

        Label:
            id: label5
            text: root.string

        TextInput:
            id: textInp1
            hint_text: 'Escribe algo:'
            multiline: True
            readonly: False

        TextInput:
            id: textInp2
            text: textInp1.text
            multiline: True
            readonly: True
            background_color: 0.92,0.89,0.75,1
            on_focus: self.focus = False
```

La app se vería algo así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se trata de un BoxLayout que contiene 5 witgets, el primero es un botón que al ser pulsado añade un nuevo número aleatorio que se muestra en el `Text input` de solo lectura que tiene al lado. El tercero es una etiqueta que muestra un texto que va cambiando automáticamente usando un temporizador, el cuarto es otro `Text input` que si permite introducir texto, el texto introducido se copia automáticamente en el último widget (otro `Text input` de solo lectura). Es solo una muestra, se pueden crear `Text input` de una sola línea, específicos para entrada de contraseñas, cambiar colores, efectos, fuentes,atajos de teclado, etc

El archivo `design.kv` es un archivo de texto y contiene la estructura de la app definida usando [Kivy Languaje](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.lang.html). Para correrlo en android usando el Launcher basta con copiarlo en la misma carpeta que `main.py` y `android.txt`. Aunque parezca complicado es realmente simple y muy poderoso, por ejemplo podemos hacer que un widget (como un botón) ocupe la mitad de la altura de su padre en todo momento (redimenciona automáticamente) con simplemente:

```
<MyWidget>:
BoxLayout:
    size: root.size

    Button:
        id: button1
        text: "Botón"
        size_hint: None, None
        height: self.parent.height/2
        width: self.parent.widht
```

Si estas empezando y medio dominas el inglés te podría venir bién ver algunos tutoriales que puedes encontrar en Youtube o en algunas webs sobre crear apps en Kivy, buscalos en Google si te interesa.

Por lo comentado en otra pregunta creo que estás intentando portar una app de Tkinter a Kivy, ten en cuenta que Kivy no es un 'emulador' de Python en Android, es un framework para crear apps con interfazes de usuario como es Tkinter(en un modo mucho más básico). Para portar tu app tendrás que buscar la forma de hacer lo que haces con Tkinter y sus widget en Kivy y los suyos. Tkinter nunca va a funcionar en Android, la idea es sustituir lo que hace tkinter con Kivy. Si tu app no es muy complicada gráficamente no tiene porque ser muy complicado, la párte lógica de tu código Python no tendrás que modificarla en principio.